# jQuery, on input[type=radio] change verify something if false, call 2 other functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, onchange

I am trying to create an event that fires some functions depending on the `id` of an `input[type=radio]`. If the Id clicked is different to `maybe_evtDiag`, it should call `this.applySubConditionalRequired();` and `this.bindUISubActions();`. Why is my code not working?

```
var SubFormStuff = {

  init: function()
    this.applySubConditionalRequired();
    this.bindUISubActions();
  },

  bindUISubActions: function() {
    // when a radio or checkbox changes value, click or otherwise
    $("input[type='radio'].stepThreeDiag").change(function() {
      if($(this).attr("id") == "maybe_evtDiag") {
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
      }else{

       //this is not working //
        applySubConditionalRequired(this);
        displaySubFormRequired(this);

      }
    });
  },

  applySubConditionalRequired: function() {
    $(".require-if-subevent-active").each(function() {
      var el = $(this);
      // does something
    });
  },

  displaySubFormRequired: function() {
    $(".div-subevent-class").each(function() {
      var el = $(this);
      // does something else
    });
  }

};

SubFormStuff.init();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you did in the `init()`, add a reference to the object (`this`) to call a sibling function (not to lose the context):

```
bindUISubActions: function() {
  var _SubFormStuff = this;
  // when a radio or checkbox changes value, click or otherwise
  $("input[type='radio'].stepThreeDiag").change(function() {
    if($(this).attr("id") == "maybe_evtDiag") {
      $(this).prop('checked', false);
    } else{    
      _SubFormStuff.applySubConditionalRequired();
      _SubFormStuff.displaySubFormRequired();
    }
  });
```

More details on [scope and context in JavaScript](http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/)

Answer (score 1):

You should call the methods like this:

```
bindUISubActions: function() {

    // Store the reference to the current object
    var self = this;

    // when a radio or checkbox changes value, click or otherwise
    $("input[type='radio'].stepThreeDiag").change(function() {
        if($(this).attr("id") == "maybe_evtDiag") {
            $(this).prop('checked', false);
        } else{
            self.applySubConditionalRequired();
            self.displaySubFormRequired();
        }
    });
 }
```

This way you can assing to `self` the current scope, and use it later on any other function call in the same execution scope.

[More about javascript scope](https://medium.com/@ankushc/scope-in-javascript-and-its-weirdness-994777cf4675)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call **applySubConditionalRequired(this)** and **displaySubFormRequired(this)** in the wrong context you should get applySubConditionalRequired and displaySubFormRequired are not defined.

Try this:

```
bindUISubActions: function() {
   // when a radio or checkbox changes value, click or otherwise
   var that = this;
   $("input[type='radio'].stepThreeDiag").change(function() {
       if($(this).attr("id") == "maybe_evtDiag") {
       $(this).prop('checked', false);
       }else{

       //it should work now //
       that.applySubConditionalRequired(this);
       that.displaySubFormRequired(this);

      }
  });
},
```